# Python Slicing an Array for Multithreading And Reassembling The Results in Order?

Tags: python, multithreading

This might have asked already here, but I couldn't come up with right keywords to search.

I have a array that I would like to split them into chunks, and hand them to threads to do some work on each slice and dump the result.

However, I need to reassemble the results from each thread in order.

I tried passing the lock for each thread to lock and dump the result into another array, but the order is not correct. I assume because each thread completes in different time.

What would be the best way to do this in Python 3?

```
import threading        
import numpy as np
from queue import Queue

def add(lock, work):
    value = 0
    for v in work:
        #Do some work!
    lock.acquire()  
    result.append(value)
    lock.release()  

a = np. arange(0,100)
result = []
lock = threading.Lock()    
q = Queue()
for i in range(0,a.shape[0],10):
    work = a[i:i+10]
    t = threading.Thread(target=add, args=(lock,work))
    t.start()
    q.put(t)

while q.empty() == False:
    q.get().join()

value = 0
for v in result:
    #Assemble
print(value)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting your results in a mixed up order because `append` puts each result at the end of the list when it comes in, which may not be in the same order the threads were started. A better approach might be to pass each worker an index into a properly-sized list, and let it assign its results there whenever it finishes. Lists are sufficiently thread-safe that you shouldn't need a lock for this (your `Queue` is also completely unnecessary since only the main thread interacts with it).

```
def add(work, result_index):
    value = 0
    for v in work:
        #Do some work!
    result[result_index] = value

a = np.arange(0,100)
results = [] 
threads = []
for i in range(0,a.shape[0],10):
    work = a[i:i+10]
    results.append(None) # enlarge the results list, so we have room for this thread's result
    t = threading.Thread(target=add, args=(work, i//10))
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)

for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

I would warn you that if your `#Do some work!` code is CPU limited, you're unlikely to get much benefit from using multiple threads. The CPython interpreter has a Global Interpreter Lock that prevents more than one thread from running Python code at the same time (so that interpreter state like reference counts on objects can remain consistent without each one needing its own lock). Threading is only really useful for IO-limited jobs (like fetching lots of documents from the internet.

For CPU limited work, you usually want to use `multiprocessing` instead. If that's what you need, look at `multiprocessing.map`, which can handle passing objects between processes and reassembling the results into an ordered list automatically.

Comment: Thanks! Ended up using multiprocessing.map!